# Python Pandas flattening a calendar with overlapping meetings to get actual time in meetings

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, dataframe

I have the details of my weekly calendar (obviously Changed the Subjects to protect the innocent) read into into a pandas dataframe.  One of my goals is to get the total time in meetings.  I would like to have a dataframe indexed by date_range with hourly frequencies for the week showing how many total minutes I was in meetings during those hours.  My first challenge is that meetings overlap and as much as I would like to be in two places at once, I am surely not.  I do hop out of one and into another though. So for example, rows at index 8 and 9 should be a total meeting time of 90 minutes and not 120 minutes as would be the case if I just df['Duration'].sum() 'd the column.  How do I flatten the time periods in the dataframe to only count the overlap once?  It seems like there is an answer somewhere using date_range and periods, but I can't wrap my head around it.  Below is my dataframe df.

```
               Start                End Duration    Subject
0   07/04/16 10:30:00  07/04/16 11:00:00    30      Inspirational Poster Design Session
1   07/04/16 15:00:00  07/04/16 15:30:00    30      Corporate Speak Do's and Don'ts
2   07/04/16 09:00:00  07/04/16 12:00:00    180     Metrics or Matrix -Panel Discussion
3   07/04/16 13:30:00  07/04/16 15:00:00    90      "Do More with Less" kickoff party
4   07/05/16 09:00:00  07/05/16 10:00:00    60      Fiscal or Physical -Panel Discussion
5   07/05/16 14:00:00  07/05/16 14:30:00    30      "Why we can't have nice thing" training video
6   07/06/16 15:00:00  07/06/16 16:00:00    60      One-on-One with manager -Panel Discussion
7   07/06/16 09:00:00  07/06/16 10:00:00    60      Fireing for Performance leadership session
8   07/06/16 13:00:00  07/06/16 14:00:00    60      Birthday Cake in the conference room *MANDATORY*
9   07/06/16 12:30:00  07/06/16 13:30:00    60      Obligatory lunchtime meeting because it was the only time everyone had avaiable
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: 
This is the output I would be hoping for with the above data set.

```
2016-07-04 00:00:00 0
2016-07-04 01:00:00 0
2016-07-04 02:00:00 0
2016-07-04 03:00:00 0
2016-07-04 04:00:00 0
2016-07-04 05:00:00 0
2016-07-04 06:00:00 0
2016-07-04 07:00:00 0
2016-07-04 08:00:00 0
2016-07-04 09:00:00 60
2016-07-04 10:00:00 60
2016-07-04 11:00:00 60
2016-07-04 12:00:00 0
2016-07-04 13:00:00 30
2016-07-04 14:00:00 60
2016-07-04 15:00:00 30
2016-07-04 16:00:00 0
2016-07-04 17:00:00 0
2016-07-04 18:00:00 0
2016-07-04 19:00:00 0
2016-07-04 20:00:00 0
2016-07-04 21:00:00 0
2016-07-04 22:00:00 0
2016-07-04 23:00:00 0
2016-07-05 00:00:00 0
2016-07-05 01:00:00 0
2016-07-05 02:00:00 0
2016-07-05 03:00:00 0
2016-07-05 04:00:00 0
2016-07-05 05:00:00 0
2016-07-05 06:00:00 0
2016-07-05 07:00:00 0
2016-07-05 08:00:00 0
2016-07-05 09:00:00 60
2016-07-05 10:00:00 0
2016-07-05 11:00:00 0
2016-07-05 12:00:00 0
2016-07-05 13:00:00 0
2016-07-05 14:00:00 30
2016-07-05 15:00:00 0
2016-07-05 16:00:00 0
2016-07-05 17:00:00 0
2016-07-05 18:00:00 0
2016-07-05 19:00:00 0
2016-07-05 20:00:00 0
2016-07-05 21:00:00 0
2016-07-05 22:00:00 0
2016-07-05 23:00:00 0
2016-07-06 00:00:00 0
2016-07-06 01:00:00 0
2016-07-06 02:00:00 0
2016-07-06 03:00:00 0
2016-07-06 04:00:00 0
2016-07-06 05:00:00 0
2016-07-06 06:00:00 0
2016-07-06 07:00:00 0
2016-07-06 08:00:00 0
2016-07-06 09:00:00 60
2016-07-06 10:00:00 0
2016-07-06 11:00:00 0
2016-07-06 12:00:00 30
2016-07-06 13:00:00 60
2016-07-06 14:00:00 0
2016-07-06 15:00:00 60
2016-07-06 16:00:00 0
2016-07-06 17:00:00 0
2016-07-06 18:00:00 0
2016-07-06 19:00:00 0
2016-07-06 20:00:00 0
2016-07-06 21:00:00 0
2016-07-06 22:00:00 0
2016-07-06 23:00:00 0
2016-07-07 00:00:00 0
```

Comment: could you post desired / expected data set?

Comment: I added the expected output.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is creating a time series (`s` below) indexed by minute that keeps tracks of whether you are in a meeting during that minute or not, and then resample that by hour. To match your desired output, you may adjust the start and end time of the index of `s`.

```
import io
import pandas as pd

data = io.StringIO('''\
Start,End,Duration,Subject
0,07/04/16 10:30:00,07/04/16 11:00:00,30,Inspirational Poster Design Session
1,07/04/16 15:00:00,07/04/16 15:30:00,30,Corporate Speak Do's and Don'ts
2,07/04/16 09:00:00,07/04/16 12:00:00,180,Metrics or Matrix -Panel Discussion
3,07/04/16 13:30:00,07/04/16 15:00:00,90,"Do More with Less" kickoff party
4,07/05/16 09:00:00,07/05/16 10:00:00,60,Fiscal or Physical -Panel Discussion
5,07/05/16 14:00:00,07/05/16 14:30:00,30,"Why we can't have nice thing" training video
6,07/06/16 15:00:00,07/06/16 16:00:00,60,One-on-One with manager -Panel Discussion
7,07/06/16 09:00:00,07/06/16 10:00:00,60,Fireing for Performance leadership session
8,07/06/16 13:00:00,07/06/16 14:00:00,60,Birthday Cake in the conference room *MANDATORY*
9,07/06/16 12:30:00,07/06/16 13:30:00,60,Obligatory lunchtime meeting because it was the only time everyone
''')
df = pd.read_csv(data, usecols=['Start', 'End', 'Subject'])
df['Start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start'])
df['End'] = pd.to_datetime(df['End'])

# Ranges in datetime indices include the right endpoint
tdel = pd.Timedelta('1min')

s = pd.Series(False, index=pd.date_range(start=df['Start'].min(),
                                         end=df['End'].max()-tdel,
                                         freq='min'))
for _, meeting in df.iterrows():
    s[meeting['Start'] : meeting['End']-tdel] = True

result = s.resample('1H').sum().astype(int)
print(result)
```

Output:

```
2016-07-04 09:00:00    60
2016-07-04 10:00:00    60
2016-07-04 11:00:00    60
2016-07-04 12:00:00     0
2016-07-04 13:00:00    30
2016-07-04 14:00:00    60
2016-07-04 15:00:00    30
2016-07-04 16:00:00     0
2016-07-04 17:00:00     0
2016-07-04 18:00:00     0
2016-07-04 19:00:00     0
2016-07-04 20:00:00     0
2016-07-04 21:00:00     0
2016-07-04 22:00:00     0
2016-07-04 23:00:00     0
2016-07-05 00:00:00     0
2016-07-05 01:00:00     0
2016-07-05 02:00:00     0
2016-07-05 03:00:00     0
2016-07-05 04:00:00     0
2016-07-05 05:00:00     0
2016-07-05 06:00:00     0
2016-07-05 07:00:00     0
2016-07-05 08:00:00     0
2016-07-05 09:00:00    60
2016-07-05 10:00:00     0
2016-07-05 11:00:00     0
2016-07-05 12:00:00     0
2016-07-05 13:00:00     0
2016-07-05 14:00:00    30
2016-07-05 15:00:00     0
2016-07-05 16:00:00     0
2016-07-05 17:00:00     0
2016-07-05 18:00:00     0
2016-07-05 19:00:00     0
2016-07-05 20:00:00     0
2016-07-05 21:00:00     0
2016-07-05 22:00:00     0
2016-07-05 23:00:00     0
2016-07-06 00:00:00     0
2016-07-06 01:00:00     0
2016-07-06 02:00:00     0
2016-07-06 03:00:00     0
2016-07-06 04:00:00     0
2016-07-06 05:00:00     0
2016-07-06 06:00:00     0
2016-07-06 07:00:00     0
2016-07-06 08:00:00     0
2016-07-06 09:00:00    60
2016-07-06 10:00:00     0
2016-07-06 11:00:00     0
2016-07-06 12:00:00    30
2016-07-06 13:00:00    60
2016-07-06 14:00:00     0
2016-07-06 15:00:00    60
Freq: H, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Almost there.  I'm getting a total when I run this (just one number), not an hourly breakdown.  Also, I found what appears to be a dangling ')' at the end of result = s.resample('1H').sum().astype(int)) .  Was that an extra parenthesis or did a statement get dropped?

Comment: Yes, that was a dangling parenthesis. Fixed it now. As for getting a single number, that doesn't make any sense to me... Maybe you're on an older version of Pandas (I'm running the latest: 0.18.1) and there is some bug in it?